# Boot process hangs at systemd-networkd-wait-online

Tags: boot, networking, systemd, systemd-networkd

When I want to boot up my laptop it shows this error to me:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd
```

[and this is what happens]

[image: 1]

Please help me.

Answer (score 17):

It sounds as if you have >1 `systemd.network(5)` configuration file in `/etc/systemd/network` (or have [Match] section specifying >1 interface with a wildcard) with none set with the `RequiredForOnline=false` directive in the `[Link]` section. In that case, `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` will expect *all* the `systemd-networkd` managed interfaces to reach a `routable` operational state.

Though setting that directive will also make it ignored by `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` entirely, which is also probably not what you want. If you don't care about ordering against the `network-online.target`, then you might as well disable and/or mask the unit.

If you would prefer to retain the advantages of ordering dependencies against `network-online.target`, then the easiest way around this that I've found is to simply use the `--any` switch. Either create the file `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/override.conf` or use `sudo systemctl edit systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` (which will also create the same file) and include these lines...

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any
```

A subsequent `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` should tell you immediately whether it worked or not.

Alternatively, you can use the `--interface=` and/or `--ignore=` switches with `systemd-networkd-wait-online`.  These may be used in place of, or in conjunction with, the `--any` switch shown above.  If used *with* the `--any` switch, it will only consider those interfaces passed to `--interface=`, or not explicitly disregarded with `--ignore=`, when determining whether the machine has reached an online state.

Comment: Why do we need `ExecStart` twice?

Comment: It is a "drop-in snippet" to add to or replace directives in the service file. Adding is as simple as including the unit section(s) and the directive(s) you wish to set, but to replace a directive that may only used once requires "clearing" the directive first. So the first one blanks out the existing ExecStart= setting, and the second is what we are replacing it with.

Comment: @WonderWoofy  -> --any  Works !!! Hope you can edit your answer to show the proper syntax for --interface=

Comment: .Also must we only add 1 --interface= or we can add few as per the nics in our server ?

Comment: @MarcoZen it is one interface name per --interface switch, but you can use the --interface switch as many times as you need. I'll update my answer for you, as there is a bit more to it than that.

Comment: Aaaaand I have no idea how to edit it on a mobile device. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ But the gist is that only one interface is allowed because you can also append a minimum and maximum operational state (basically the state it must reach to be considered "up", or 'routable' if unspecified). Just like the -o or --operational switch, but specific to one interface. Glad my answer helped you out though! I'll fix my answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @WonderWoofy - what would the  syntax be for NetworkManager-wait-online - Failed to Start ? It must be something similar ? This happens because of 2 NICs i suppose ?  How do you find what put into ExecStart ?

Comment: @MarcoZen - I don't know what NetworkManager-wait-online needs, as i don't use it. I actually just read the man page to figure out the systemd-networkd-wait-online args. I imagine Network Manager's might also have a man page. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @WonderWoofy - man   /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-wait-online.service

Comment: @MarcoZen I'm confused by that last response. That isn't how you see man pages.  In this case, the documentation info should be a directive in the service file.  This means that you _should_ be able to do `systemctl help NetworkManager-wait-online.service` and it will take you to the appropriate man page. (For that service, it seems that the man page is actually `nm-online`. So you can also use `man nm-online` or `man 1 nm-online` as well.)

Comment: Oof, that one works entirely differently.  By default the service runs `nm-online -s -q -t 30`, where the `-s` (or `--wait-for-startup`) makes it report success when NetworkManager simply comes up properly, the `-q` is short for `--quiet`, and the `-t 30` is equivalent to `--timeout=30`.  So it appears that the removal of the `-s` switch should cause it to react to network connectivity rather than the state of `NetworkManager.service`.  You can use a drop-in snippet for this too, which I describe above.

Comment: Didn't help. Not sure why. I ended up disabling it completely using `sudo systemctl disable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` and that worked.

Answer (score 7):

Your system is not freezing during the boot process, it's entered a waiting state for the network devices to be completely configured before continuing on. The ultimate fix will come from an examination of of the configuration files in `/etc/systemd/network` and the service logs as revealed by `journalctl -xe | grep networkd`, focusing your attention on any links whose status in the report from `networkctl status -a` is not listed as "configured". This has been known to happen when IPv6 is unavailable or misconfigured, but also for various other reasons.

You should reboot the system in recovery mode via your bootloader (GRUB, rEFInd, etc.) and select the root option from the menu that appears. From there you can examine the system with the above-mentioned commands and/or enable debugging logs for the service by creating a new directory with `mkdir /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d` and then creating a new file in it called override.conf (e.g. `sudoedit /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d/override.conf`) with the following contents:

```
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

You can test the success of your modifications to the files in `/etc/systemd/network` while still in recovery mode using the command `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online && echo $?`. If you've fixed the problem the output will be 0. Failing all else, you can disable the service entirely with `sudo systemctl disable systemd-netword-wait-online.service`

---

Relevant man pages:

- [systemd-networkd-wait-online(8)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.html)
- [systemd-networkd(8)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd.service.html)
- [systemd.network(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html)

Comment: I did what you said(i disabled systemctl)but it didn't work.

Comment: If you really wanted to make systemd-networkd-wait-online.service not start up, then Peter's suggestion of using `systemctl disable ...` should work.  But another systemd unit could be starting it as a dependency still.  If you really want to forcefully prevent it from starting, then mask it with  `systemctl mask systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`.  Just beware that the `network-online.target` has a dependency on one of the "wait-online" services, and that `network-online.target` may be used to ensure network connectivity prior to firing up other services.

Comment: In any case, my answer below will fix your issue if it is something you're still fighting against.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu can use either `systemd-networkd` (default on servers) or `NetworkManager` (default on desktops) to manage networking. As a result there are two wait services: `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` and `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`. If you have the wrong one enabled (or as in my case, both enabled), then the service will timeout. You can check what you have enabled with the following command:

```
~# systemctl is-enabled NetworkManager-wait-online.service systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
enabled
enabled
```

In this instance, as you can see, I have both enabled. You can further see which service is being used by asking systemd:

```
# systemctl is-enabled NetworkManager.service systemd-networkd.service
enabled
enabled
```

As you can see, on my system, both network services are enabled. I'm running a desktop machine, so NetworkManager is mostly likely to be the correct service. I can validate this by looking in `/etc/netplan/` and seeing that  `networkmanager.yaml` exists. Further inspection of the `netplan` configuration files validates that NetworkManager is aware of all the interfaces on my machine. So I disable `systemd-networkd`

```
# systemctl disable systemd-networkd.service
Removed /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/systemd-networkd.socket.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/systemd-networkd.service.
```

Note that this has also disabled the wait service, and some associated other services. So this is significantly better than just disabling the wait service. Now my boot time has reduced from just over two minutes, to less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! In particular, this happens when you install ubuntu-server (which apparently is on `networkd`) and then install the desktop (which prefers `NetworkManager`).